# Twitter Bootstrap Transition Conflict prototypejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, prototypejs

I created a fiddle for Collapse feature of Twitter Bootstrap using the markup from the demos on your page that works: http://jsfiddle.net/Rymd7/1/

Then once, I add in a reference to prototypejs collapse functionality stops working on each accordian group after clicking through it a couple of times.  http://jsfiddle.net/p5SAy/1/    I'm not sure what the issue is or how to correct it.

Is this a bootstrap issue or is there a way to get around this and have these two js libraries exist on the same page?

I have tried jQuery noConflict with no success, but any help is appreciated.
If you can send me back a working fiddle that would be great...or any insight.

Thanks.  -John

Comment: These two fiddles are identical.  Did you mean to do that?

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5403 - is it yours?

Comment: @davehale23 The two fiddles are different.  As posed in the original question, the 2nd one has a reference to prototype.js.  You will see it under managed resources.

Comment: @Victor Yes that is my question on github.

Answer (score 17):

You are using jQuery and Prototype simultaneously without `jQuery.noConflict()`. After

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0/prototype.js"></script>
```

this line was causing javascript error:

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

Revised fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ymbsr/5/ - open http://fiddle.jshell.net/ymbsr/5/show/ in different browsers.

P.S.

After removing jQuery/Prototype conflict I can see that ih Chrome 21 and Opera 12.02 accordion transition never ends (in `bootstrap-collapse.js` `Collapse.transition` initiates transition but `complete()` is never called). Further invocations of `Collapse.show()/hide()` on the same element are exiting after `if (this.transitioning) return`.

In Firefox 15.0.1 accordion works fine.

P.P.S.

This strange behavior is a consequence of two features:

1. `this.$element.trigger('hide')` (in `Collapse#transition()`) tries to invoke `$element.hide()` if method `hide()` is present in element - that's [by design](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

   > Note: For both plain objects and DOM objects, if a triggered event
   >   name matches the name of a property on the object, jQuery will attempt
   >   to invoke the property as a method if no event handler calls
   >   event.preventDefault(). If this behavior is not desired, use
   >   .triggerHandler() instead.

   With Prototype in each browser supporting HTML element prototype extensions `$element` will definitely have `hide()` method, which actually hides element via setting `element.style.display = 'none'`.
2. In current versions of Chrome and Opera transition end event (one of `webkitTransitionEnd`, `oTransitionEnd`, `otransitionend`) will not fire if element is hidden (has `display: none` style). Firefox ends its transition more successfully, but also [may not fire event under some circumstances](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition):

   > Note: The "transitionend" event doesn't fire if the transition is aborted because the animating property's value is changed before the transition is completed.

How to fix it:

1. File a bug for `bootstrap-collapse.js` - it shouldn't [rely only on transition end event](http://heydanno.com/blog/2010/03/07/detecting-transition-event-support/)
2. File a bug for `bootstrap-collapse.js` - its `hide` event intersects with other frameworks (at least with Prototype, but any other framework extending element prototypes may be affected).
3. Temporarily patch `Collapse#transition()` from `bootstrap-collapse.js` as in http://fiddle.jshell.net/ymbsr/7/ - either disable event triggering or change event names.

   ```
   jQuery.fn.collapse.Constructor.prototype.transition = function (method, startEvent, completeEvent) {
     var that = this
       , complete = function () {
           if (startEvent.type == 'show') that.reset();
           that.transitioning = 0;
           that.$element.trigger(completeEvent);
         }
     //this.$element.trigger(startEvent);
     //if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return;
     this.transitioning = 1;
     this.$element[method]('in');
     (jQuery.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('collapse')) ?
         this.$element.one(jQuery.support.transition.end, complete) :
         complete();
   };
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I have added in jQuery.noConflict() if you can take a look at this : http://fiddle.jshell.net/ymbsr/3/show/  . The broken behavior still exists and the javascript errors are gone.

Comment: More correct version: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ymbsr/5/ - each node shows/collapses only once, next clicks are not working. No script errors. Strange enough. Will look into it.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ymbsr/6/ - either without bootstrap-transition.js or without prototype collapse works fine - IMHO this is conflict between transition and prototype and should be asked on bootstrap support forum

Comment: Yes.  That is about is far as I have gotten.  I cannot figure out what the issue is with transitions.  Our business has a need for them to glide smoothly like that, so I'm curious to resolve this issue if possible.  I posted the question on github, but they closed the issue as it is a compatibility issue of managing two different javascript libraries and is not solely a Bootstrap issue on its own.  I may have to just find a different jQuery accordion that does not conflict, but I was posting here hoping that someone might be able to help.  Thanks for yours!

Comment: @Victor - if I'm understanding you correctly, that the problem is that trigger is causing some prototype extensions to fire, wouldn't the simplest patch be to replace `this.$element.trigger(startEvent);` with `this.$element.triggerHandler(startEvent);`?  That seems to work, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: @AdamRackis yes, `element.trigger('hide')` will invoke `element.hide()` if it exists exactly as `element.trigger('click')` will invoke `element.click()`, no matter if it is native method or added via `element`/`element.prototype` extension; and yes, `triggerHandler` may help in this particular case (the other way is to rename `show` and `hide` events)

Comment: @Victor your patch has worked for my setup, I was experiencing the same issue (collapse would only work once - and the 'hide' had no transition animation, the body would immediately collapse). Thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: @Victor The patch worked beautifully, pasted it in and bingo. Been searching for a fix for 2 days now, thanks

Comment: @Victor: you got the secret sauce! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Magento and have had [bootstrap/ prototype problems](http://www.softec.lu/site/DevelopersCorner/BootstrapPrototypeConflict) for years. I tried all of the above without luck. Ha you will not believe what worked!

I moved prototype as one of the first scripts to be loaded and left all of the others to be loaded after. That worked for me. I dont know why I didnt try the earlier.