# Bootstrap jquery methods Magento's prototype lib

Tags: magento, twitter-bootstrap, prototype, jquery

Wonder if anyone has had this issue.
I've integrated Bootstrap nicely into a Magento theme I'm building, all good.

That is, until I try using the accordian functions. There seems to be an issue with the code finding the Prototype Libs Methods instead of jQuery's. I've tried the usual fixes, $ - jQuery and no conflict but it only works when I disable the prototype lib - which obviously is not good.

Anyone out there come across this and can advise me on a work round? At the moment I'm resigned to using Scriptaculous for the accordian.

Comment: show your console. Firefox  & chrome = ctrl+shift+j

Comment: Are you sure you did `jQuery.noConflict` immediately after jQuery was included, before any other code is run?

Comment: Hi The jS fires but incorrectly as its using the prototype lib not the jquery one. I think. Here's the url http://onebellmag.preview3.co.uk/magento/content/terms-conditions

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is occurring due to the transitional conflict in prototype which is used in Magento front-end and admin areas.

Please see: [Twitter Bootstrap Transition Conflict prototypejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715254/twitter-bootstrap-transition-conflict-prototypejs)

You can try this library: https://github.com/jwestbrook/bootstrap-prototype and see if it resolves your issue you are having with your accordian.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery in Magento can be sometimes tricky. I normally make something like:
`jquery-ui-1.8.9.noconflict.min.js`

and put `jQuery.noConflict()` right at the end of the file.

Also make sure that jQuery is loaded **after** Prototype & there is only 1 version of jQuery included on any page.

I normally like to use jQuery instead of $ all the time but I guess anonymous functions should work too:

```
(function($) {  /* use $ here */  })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js use below  js files to get the solution.

1. jquery.js
2. prettify.js
3. bootstrap-transition.js
4. bootstrap-alert.js
5. bootstrap-modal.js
6. bootstrap-dropdown.js
7. bootstrap-scrollspy.js
8. bootstrap-tab.js
9. bootstrap-tooltip.js
10. bootstrap-popover.js
11. bootstrap-button.js
12. bootstrap-collapse.js
13. bootstrap-carousel.js
14. bootstrap-typeahead.js
15. application.js more if required.